# jQuery on delegate selectors - not supporting my selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `on()` event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() { 
    alert('hi');
});
```

When a button is clicked, I successfully get an alert box.

However I want to filter out some buttons. I attach some custom data to buttons that I want to filter out: `data-confirm=true`.

I know I can write a selector for this which works when run in Chrome's developer console:

```
$('.btn [data-confirm!="true"]')
```

This returns all buttons without a `data-confirm` attribute set to true.

However, when I add this to my `on()` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn [data-confirm!="true"]', function() { 
    alert('hi');
});
```

... my event handler is never called (whether `data-confirm` is set or not).

Is there some issue with the extra complexity in the selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the space between your class and your attribute.

You can also use jQuery [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn:not([data-confirm="true"])', function() { 
    alert('hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">I'm working</button>
<button class="btn" data-confirm="true">I'm not :(</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! But why does the selector work when run from the console?

Comment: @DanGravell It doesn't when I try it.

Comment: I think I might be mistaken - it actually looks like it's returning multiple matches, including none `.btn` matches - like the two clauses in the selector have been ORed?

Comment: If you're talking about what you see in console after your selector, you're seeing a jQuery object, still containing some informations. To see if it found anything, check the `length` property.

Comment: Be careful about the context of your command. There might be 37 `.btn` on the Stackoverflow page, but not in the snippet.

Comment: Sorry - I meant on the page on which this code runs. Don't worry - thanks for the fix, which has worked.